# Why is Jenkinsfile also cloned into the slave repo while using Git SCM Plugin

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have noticed that when I clone a git repo containing the Jenkinsfile via the Git SCM plugin then not only is a clone made in the master node but the same repo is also cloned in the slave node as well.

Any reason why this cloning happens on the slave end as well or what is the purpose ?

If I suppose have further git cloning operations inside the Jenkinsfile (may be some other repository which I need) then that will overwrite the originally cloned repo in the slave node unless i change the directory specifically.

Comment: The Jenkins slave is where the commands in the Jenkinsfile run; it must have the file (and the repository with the files that are to be used here) so that it can read the commands to run.

Comment: @torek but as I said if my jenkinsfile itself contains a cloning operation of some other repo then that clone operation will overwrite whatever was cloned earlier which also removes the Jenkinsfile. How is that scenario handled ?

Comment: `git clone` always makes a *new, empty directory* into which it places the clone. So your additional clone(s) merely add on to your existing set of clone(s) so far.